# faster way to multiply each entry by a column

Tags: r

I have a data frame g with 3 columns, a, b and X. I need to multiply X with each entry in a and add to b to create a new variable. Right now i'm using a for loop

```
for(i in 1:N) {
    g$Eout[i] = mean((g$a[i]*g$X+g$b[i]-(g$X)^2)^2);
}
```

which is really slow in R. Is there anyway to do this faster?

Comment: reproducible example please?

Comment: Here's a 30K row reproducible example @RichScriven - `N <- 3e4; g <- data.frame(a=1:N,b=seq(1,2,length.out=N),X=seq(10,20,length.out=N))` - go at it with a benchmark. :-)

Comment: I think you need to move some `mean()`s around.

Comment: Does this apply X to each entry of a and b? From what I see it seems to apply X and a

Comment: I think we do need a repro example.  I'm not sure what `X` is supposed to be.

Comment: g=data.frame(a=runif(N,-1,1),b=runif(N,-1,1),X=runif(N,-1,1)). I hope this helps understand what I'm asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
set.seed(2)
N <- 30
g <- data.frame(a=1:N,b=seq(1,2,length.out=N),X=seq(10,20,length.out=N))
g$new <- sapply(g$X, function(x) mean((g$a * x + g$b - x^2)^2))
head(g)
#   a        b        X      new
# 1 1 1.000000 10.00000 10735.67
# 2 2 1.034483 10.34483 11077.04
# 3 3 1.068966 10.68966 11416.58
# 4 4 1.103448 11.03448 11757.01
# 5 5 1.137931 11.37931 12101.40
# 6 6 1.172414 11.72414 12453.14
```

Since you want each value of `X` multiplying *all* values of `g$a`, etc, you need to resort to some vectorized goodness. (Using @thelatemail's suggested `3e4` takes about 7sec per `sapply` ...)

Comment: Could probably speed it up more with `vapply()` with `FUN.VALUE = double(1)`

Comment: Thanks! In generally we use some function of apply to do loops in R I suppose. This is really useful.